# What are 'sulphate particles' in the context of atmospheric chemistry?

Tags: atmosphere, atmospheric-chemistry

[This informative answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/9999/6031) describes some processes in atmospheric chemistry and mentions "sulphate particles".

Actually I realize that I don't know what a 'sulphate particle' really is, though I've heard the term many times. [Sulphate is an ion, or an anion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfate), so the term could refer to a solid particle of some sulphate salt (e.g. calcium sulphate, sodium sulphate) or balanced by some other caution in solution in a water droplet, but is there such a thing as a particle made of "pure sulphate"?

$\hskip3.8cm$[image]

$\hskip3.7cm$**above:** "Sulfate-ion-2D-dimensions", from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sulfate-ion-2D-dimensions.png).